# error when install mysqlclient using pip to MacOS Bigsur

Tags: mysql, pip, clang, zstd

I've tried common solutions written for mysqlclient error

- 1st try: `brew install mysql-connector-c`
- 2nd try:
  `LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib pip install mysqlclient`
- 3rd try: `brew install zstd`

And mysql server is well-running.
But the error is not being fixed..

I am getting `clang linker error` saying `library not found for -lzstd`

```
    clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/Users/user/.asdf/installs/python/3.7.10/lib -L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib -L/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/Users/user/.asdf/installs/python/3.7.10/lib -L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib -L/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib -L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include build/temp.macosx-11.2-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/_mysql.o -L/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.25_1/lib -lmysqlclient -lzstd -lresolv -o build/lib.macosx-11.2-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-37m-darwin.so
ld: library not found for -lzstd
clang-12: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In my case I did not had the sudo access so installed brew for my user
**Check if your brew is not in default location**
do this to check where you have installed brew

```
brew --prefix
output: Users/helloWorld/homebrew
```

use the output of above to set the ld flags and cpp flags
for example for me ssl and zstd libs were not found so this is what i did:

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/Users/helloWorld/homebrew/lib -L/Users/helloWorld/homebrew/opt/openssl/lib"

export CPPFLAGS="-I/Users/helloWorld/homebrew/include -I/Users/helloWorld/homebrew/opt/openssl/include"
```

and then do the pip install

```
pip3 install mysqlclient
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! You saved so much time for me :)

Comment: Happy to help! Cheers!

Comment: I've had exactly the same issue, done exactly like Rauhl said, except now it says `ld: can't map file, errno=22 file '/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl/lib' for architecture arm64` :(
been struggling with this for 3 days now smh

Comment: Hi Ovi, could you share the commands you tried before this error message.

Comment: I have made a small edit @Ovi Could you please try again. Earlier somehow i missed a hyphen before the second L.

`export LDFLAGS="-L/Users/helloWorld/homebrew/lib -L/Users/helloWorld/homebrew/opt/openssl/lib"`

Comment: Hey @RahulRai, I have tried different commands until I got the path of the openssl right, resulting in the error above. One answer that has worked for me, was this one -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/67907401/9686563